# teechart trend possible in standard version?

Tags: teechart, trendline

I have Teechart v7.10 that shipped with Delphi 2007, which is the standard version. Is it possible to add a trend line to my charts or do I have to use the Pro version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [feature matrix](http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl), the Trend function is only supported in the Pro version, as the other functions.

However, you can always do the calculations yourself and add the calculated points to a new `TLineSeries`.

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thanks! Do you happen to know of any examples of making a trend using TLineSeries?